# Is there a way to not override $.ajaxSetup success function?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using `$.ajaxSetup` for some actions, but I also need to declare a couple of custom actions on the call itself. Can I do this without overriding the `$.ajaxSetup`? In other words, I want to run the code inside `success` defined in the `ajaxSetup` but also the one defined on the `$.ajax` call. Is this possible?

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  success: function(data, textStatus, request) {
    a();
  },
});

$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:8000/api/auth/user",
  type: 'GET',
  success: function() {
    b();
  }
});
```

On a successful call, I want to run both `a()` and `b()`, not just `b()`.

Comment: No, it's either/or. You cannot do both. *However*, you could run one function in `success` and the other in `complete`, but note that this is a little hacky as `complete` will be called even if the request fails, so it's probably not a good idea.

Comment: I do not recommend you to set default `success` handler using `ajaxSetup`. You could use [`.ajaxSuccess`](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) to setup global success event handler instead.